# class.forname() giving the "driverclass" as exception

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, netbeans-7

I used the following code segment for connecting my java application to mySQL DB, but its giving an error which I can't figure out why.

```
try {
  con = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String db = "ass1";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String user = "";
  String pass = "";

  System.out.println("OK 1"); //Checkpoint 1

  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

  System.out.println("OK 2"); //Checkpoint 2

  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);

  System.out.println("OK 3"); //Checkpoint 3
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Exception(Output):

```
run:
OK 1
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL(total time: 13 seconds)
```

So the exception is driver itself. It's the first time that I'm encountering this.

P.S.: Please ignore the checkpoints.

Comment: is the driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" in your class path? and no need to call newInstance(),just use Class.forName(driver);

Comment: Check for the jar supporting the class has been added or is available in the classpath. I think the jar is mysql-connector.jar

Comment: In addition to below answer Its optional to use`Class.forName()` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28220350/3841803

Comment: You should really use `printStackTrace()` instead of **only** getting the message. The exception-type itself is important information; most likely you get a `ClassNotFoundException` as you don't have the MySQL JDBC driver on your classpath.

Comment: That line of code hasn't been needed since 2007.

Answer (score 1):

No Need to call **newInstance()** method .

```
Class.forName(driver);
```

is enough.  Check that the required jar is available in your build path or not ?

---

Another Suggestion

Always try to use `printStackTrace()` instaed of `getMessage()`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to instantiate the driver, just call it's static initialization (e.g., by calling `Class.forName`) so it gets registered in the `DriverManager`:

```
System.out.println("OK 1"); //Checkpoint 1

Class.forName(driver); // no .newInstance() !

System.out.println("OK 2"); //Checkpoint 2

con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
```

Comment: You don't even need to call `Class.forName` since Java 6 (if you have a JDBC 4 compliant driver) as drivers are now loaded using the `ServiceLoader`-mechanism.